# nullPointerException on a nullable=false value

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

This method does the following : it gets the int startAge from the Database. This parameter has a set default of 0 and is not nullable. Then it checks if it´s bigger than zero, in which case it adds it to dob and returns it.

Pretty simple, actually, but i keep getting a NullPointerException on the marked line, although the Database makes sure the variable CANNOT be null and the parameter groupFrom in the entity class is also set to nullable=false.

Any hints ?

```
public static DateMidnight getRealStartDate(DateMidnight startDate, DateMidnight dob, Groups group){
    DateMidnight realStart = null;
    int startAge = group.getGroupFrom(); //nullPointerException
    if (startAge > 0) {
        realStart = dob.plusMonths(startAge);
    } else {
        realStart = startDate;
    }   
    return realStart;
}
```

Comment: You should provide more information: how do you call the method? Are you sure you fetched `group`? Didi you try with a debugger to see what happens?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What's preventing `group` from being null?

Comment: Without any extra information: group is null or something inside getGroupFrom() being used is null.

Comment: how do you call this method. and where do you instantiate group ?

Comment: use assertions in your code, "assert group != null;" for example. re-run and see..

Comment: Unrelated, but having an instance of plural `Groups` referred to by the singular `group` is a little confusing; seems like they should match. (And `getGroupFrom` without any arguments seems like it should be just `getGroup`?)

Comment: The method is called as part of a larger process and is only called when a group is chosen, so group truly can´t be null. But, i did have a group record with null in groupFrom . Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a NullPointerException at that line it means that the variable group is null.

Comment: or GetGroupFrom() returns a java.lang.Integer that is null.

Comment: As has already been well pointed out in the comments to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's ugly. If you cannot use a debugger:

Insert these lines on your second line:

```
if (group == null) {
  System.out.println("group is null");
} else {
  System.out.println("group isn't null");
}
```

I'm sure it will print *"group is null"*, because something with your assumptions is not working.

You could use tools like `log4j` or `slf4j` for doing a more professional output. :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that there is data in the database that has `group == null`.  Although group is set with `nullable=false` this is only an `INSERT` restriction as far as I know.  There is probably rows already in the database with a null group.  Maybe another entity is inserting data that does not have the nullable restriction?

Can you do a query of the database looking for null groups to see if they exist?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo WHERE 'group' IS NULL;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You´re right. There was a null in the table,  it´s some orphaned record from the development stage of the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Better use assertions where your not completely sure in your code. In the *group* example

```
 DateMidnight realStart = null;
 assert group != null;
 int startAge = group.getGroupFrom(); //nullPointerException
```

Answer (score 1):

To state what the others have said slightly differently, you might be confusing the value of the field in the database which is probably not NULL, with the value of the object group in the call below.  The getGroupFrom Method could also have a bug in it that is preventing it from returning the correct value from the database.

```
group.getGroupFrom()
```